# How can this Geometric Brownian Motion Parameter Estimator be without loops?

Tags: python, numpy

How can the function below be done without the numpy.vectorize function, which is a shorthand for loop, and become completely loop-less?

It uses a geometic brownian motion to create a single path for an imaginary stock with initial price one with the assumed beginning volatility of 0.5 and mean of 0.3.

Then, based on the formulas for estimating the volatility and mean of the geometic brownian motion, it returns the estimates for a given number of steps.

To provide meaningful, graphable data, I had to use a "hidden" for-loop that tries for a range of different time steps, from 1 to 2^no, the format for the steps wanted by the question.

My question is, is there a way to do it without that loop? I need it without the numpy.vectorize as the question actually wants the code to be loop-free.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math as m
from scipy.stats import norm
from matplotlib import pyplot as pt

#Plot Code
def plotter(xlabel,ylabel,title):
    pt.xlabel(xlabel)
    pt.ylabel(ylabel)
    pt.title(title)
    pt.legend()
    
def dw_one_gbm(no):
    np.random.seed(12345678)
    dw = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(2**no))*m.sqrt(1/(2**no))
    dw[0] = 0.0
    return dw

#A
def vol_n_mean(no,lis,sigma=0.5,mu=0.3):
    S = np.exp(sigma*np.cumsum(dw_one_gbm(no)))*np.exp((mu-(0.5*(sigma**2)))*np.linspace(0,1,2**no))
    sg = np.std(np.log(S[1::]/S[:-1:])[:lis:])/((1/(2**no))**0.5)
    mn = (np.mean(np.log(S[1::]/S[:-1:])[:lis:])/(1/(2**no))) + ((sg**0.5)/2)
    return sg, mn

def grapher(no):
    sg, mn = np.vectorize(vol_n_mean)(no,(2**(np.arange(0,no))))
    
    pt.figure(2, figsize=(10,5)).add_subplot(211)
    pt.semilogx((2**(np.arange(0,no))),sg,'o',color="orange",label="Calculated")
    pt.axhline(0.5,label="Real")
    plotter("Time Steps","Sigma","Sigma Semilog from Estimation")
    
    pt.figure(2, figsize=(10,5)).add_subplot(212)
    pt.semilogx((2**(np.arange(0,no))),mn,'o',color="orange",label="Calculated")
    pt.axhline(0.3,label="Real")
    plotter("Time Steps","Mean","Mean Semilog from Estimation")
    
grapher(18)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that we say 'vectorize' in `numpy` we mean  moving the loops into compiled code.  There still are loops, but we don't care about the order.  From outside the action is applied to all elements at once.  It's a parallel view of the data or calculation as opposed to a sequential, serial view.  Only a few of the `ufunc` have a useful `accumulate` or `reduce` that operate sequentially.

Comment: is there a way to do it like with the numpy.log(s[1::]/s[:-1:]) type of coding, only with array/vector operations? @hpaulj

Comment: I am not sure that I understand which is the hidden loop you have in your code. To test different `$\deta_t$` you must recur, or you have to provide the generative GBM function with a set of `$\delta_t$`, anyway, you will not escape from vectorising. I do no think you can do much better than you are doing.